# How to add multiple markers and infowindow using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google map API V3 to draw routes. I am having 'LatLng' array and I am looping this array to plot route on map.and I also need to add markers and infowindow for each address. I am getting markers on the map, But info window dose not work, Here is my Code.

```
for(i=0;i<s[0].length;i++)
{
marker[count] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: s[0][i]["location"],
                    map: map
                });



marker[count].info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<b>Speed:</b> '
        });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker[count], 'click', function() 
  {
     marker[count].info.open(map, marker[count]);
  });

count++;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
marker[count].info.open(map, marker[count]);
```

You may

```
this.info.open(map, this);
```

Here is a tutorial on [multiple makers with infowindow.](http://theoryapp.com/google-maps-with-multiple-markers-and-infowindow/)